# Droid Library Thinks it's Wearable How do I make it Un-wearable?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a solution with 4 projects 2 PCL's, a Droid Library and a droid App. When I reference the Droid Library from my Droid Application at compile I'm getting:

Error XA5211: Embedded wear app package name differs from handheld app package name.

In both Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio.

Thing is it's not a wear app package nor do I have a handheld app package. Im just trying to reference a Library I created from an android App I created. I cant find any settings in either the csproj file the sln or the IDE that have changed that made my driod library into a wearable library (Im sure I changed something just dont know what) Its here somewhere just no idea were or what I'm looking for besides scanning for the word wear which doesn't seem to show up anywhere. I looked back through my change history and I dont see where it got messed up at.

Until last week everything was fine. Then I started trying to get the latest release of Xamarin.Forms to allow my code to compile. I changed a number of settings over a week of debugging that issue and finally got everything to work again by setting my target Platform to 6.0 and downloading the latest Android SDK.

The Libraries I'm attempting to reference that cause the issue I have on GitHub @ https://github.com/Indiponics/IndiXam-Lib in case anyone cares to look at the csproj file etc.

Comment: Ensure you haven't selected an Android version with `W` in it (ie. `4.4W`)

Comment: I remember changing the target platform to a 4.?w at one point last week but now its set to Use Latest(6.0)

Comment: Hmm, maybe select 6 manually (the option above Use latest) and try again

Comment: Blew away all the references and redid them and that seems to have fixed it in Visual Studio however Xamarin Studio is still showing the error.

Comment: Strange, in my case I'm on minimum 18 / target 18. Far from the 4.4W (API 20).

Comment: Edit: Oh, there was some issue with identicals name and name scopes when refering another Android project. Nothing to do with wearable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is easy. Open the `.csproj` file of your Android app and find the project reference you need to work. It might look like this:

`<ProjectReference Include="..\MyWearApp\MyWearApp.csproj">
    <Project>{D80E1FEF-653B-448C-B2AA-609C74E88340}</Project>
    <Name>MyWearApp</Name>
    <IsAppExtension>True</IsAppExtension>
</ProjectReference>`

The problem is with the extension part. Simply remove the `IsAppExtension` line and any other than `Project` and `Name`. It should work now.

I think we lost an entire man-week on this issue!

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/wear/working-with/packaging/

Comment: The good old "solution is easy" when you can tell someone in 8 seconds what it took you "a week of pain to work out the hard way" :) thank you.